# Dashboard above the fold? Is it possible

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing, info-visualisation, dashboard

curious to know is it possible to provide contents in dashboard above the fold -no scroll in page. Attaching the reference template. Please provide your suggestions. FYI, it is a KPI strategic kind of dashboard. User only views data in form of table/chart, download CSV, PDF.[image]

[image]

Comment: Not entirely clear what the question is here.

Comment: can we have no page scroll dashboard?

Comment: I am still not sure what you're asking. Do you want to **not** have a scrollbar?

Comment: YES. do not want scrollbar in the dashboard. have multiple widgets on the page. Above reference template.

Comment: If you don't want a scrollbar then you can simply limit the no. of widgets per page and ask the user to add pages/tabs if they want more widgets. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: You can switch off scrollbars, but why would you? What will you do about overflowing content, as the user changes browser window size or accesses the website via mobile, etc?

Comment: This is desktop alone application. For overflowing content can we show like i shown in reference image with a drop  down to access each widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scrolling is inevitable: Allow users to arrange content in order of importance for them.

Scrolling is inevitable, and since viewport size is hard to control for, allow your users ability to arrange content according to what's most important for them. *Bias towards the top of the viewport.*

You have 2 choices for the user for the design you have presented:

#### 1. For Data Tables: Allow sorting and pinning.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftcN4a.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This allows you to:

- Keep content above the fold (in conjunction with sizing the elements for various viewports)
- **Let the user decide what is important for them to view first**
- If you cap the number of table rows, you might test if there's other visualization types that belong with a tabular view, rather then a full switch to another type (but I don't know your users)

### 2. For **graphic visualization:** break data into arrangeable modules.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9wSKb.png)</sup>

This allows the same 'above the fold' ability to the users.

You're fortunate in that for strategic dashboards, time and consequences are not as immediate as in an Operational Dashboard, where if I can't see it, it doesn't exist (and disaster may strike).

Scrolling will still exist, but you can at least give more power to your users for the top of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for above suggestions. This is Desktop application. Consider the scenario where 1. For Data Tables: Allow sorting and pinning. -> I have 10 tables like you have shown so scroll needs to be on screen to access all the tables. But my ask is can we provide a way without scroll on page like i shown in reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you develop the dashboard responsively. There are many libraries whose components are responsive in nature and will adjust to the size of your screen.

What we did developing a dashboard (before the days of responsive) was that we took to resolution of the screen where the dashboard was to be displayed (in this case an LCD screen back then) and design a full screen view fit for the LCD screen (no horizontal or vertical scrolling) and a regular computer view that just kept scrolling vertically until all the information was displayed. The computer view included all the actions like export, and the full screen LCD display included only information such as gauges, bar charts and tables.